# Is there a command line 'command' for creating the controller and view files?

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to know if there is a command to run on my terminal that will create the controller and view directories and files based on my input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out: [Generating a CRUD Controller Based on a Doctrine Entity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html).

Comment: My bundle has already been created with your above command, I meant something to speed up the creation of additional pages like with ZendFramework you have the command **zf create controller** which will create the controller file and the view files

Comment: Yes I can work with that and just edit what I don't need, thank you Samy!

Comment: You are welcome. Be careful though, it may seem a good thing when you want to do things quickly, or don't know the framework good enough, but it'll become harder to maintain as the project grows. You'll realize it on your own anyway, I guess. Good luck! :)

Comment: As samy said, it's good for prototyping and learning but do not rely on them for too long

Comment: You don't need your code base to grow with features that you do not use (you most of the time need creation and reading, but updating and deletion is less common), and security wise, take care of the generated routes that you do not use.